# Patch/Merge plugin.properties file in plugin by using fragment

Tags: eclipse, plugins, merge, patch, fragment

In my plugin de.support.help  are the plugin.properties files.
These properties files include the strings for the preference page.

I want to use this plugin for different customers, but the customer name is inside the  properties files.

I want to patch the properties files by using the eclipse fragment mechanism. As far as i now the fragment plugin can patch the coresponding plugin at runtime.

I do have the file plugin.properties in plugin de.support.help which includes the line

```
plugin.name = Copyright XYZ
```

And i do have the fragemt de.support.help.fragment which includes the file plugin.properties with line

```
plugin.name = Copyright ABC
```

I expect that at runtime the string "Copyright ABC" is shown, but it is not. I had tested the same with java classes a long time ago and i remember that t his was working. The java code from the fragment was placed to the original plugin.

Do you have any idea to handle this? Or do i misunderstand the fragment mechanism?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

When i remove the plugin.properties file from the de.support.help plugin it works as expected. The fragment file is copied into the plugin directory and is used at runtime.

Or do i have to patch the somce eclipse class [Can_fragments_be_used_to_patch_a_plug](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Can_fragments_be_used_to_patch_a_plug-in%3F)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i have implemented is like

First look for special fragment property file and than look for the default property file.

The code is (Bundle names were changed)

```
public final class FrameworkMessages {
    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "de.rts.messages"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private static final ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);

    private static final String BUNDLE_FRAGMENT_NAME = "de.rts.fragment"; //$NON-NLS-1$


    private FrameworkMessages() {
    }

    public static String getString(String key) {
        try {
            return ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_FRAGMENT_NAME).getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            // Use messages in this plugin when no external fragment files can found
        }

        try {
            return RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return '!' + key + '!';
        }
    }

    public static String getString(String pKey, Object[] pArgument) {
        try {
            return MessageFormat.format(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(pKey), pArgument);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return '!' + pKey + '!';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [**How to Internationalize your Eclipse Plug-In**](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Internationalization/how2I18n.html) article

> A plug-in fragment provides additional functionality to its target plug-in.
>   At runtime, these plug-in contributions are merged along with all dependent fragments.
>
> These contributions can include code contributions and contributions of resources associated with a plug-in, like property and HTML files.
>
> In other words, the plug-in has access to the fragment's contents via the plug-in's classloader.
>
> The Eclipse Platform merges plug-in fragments in a way that the runtime elements in the fragment augment the original targeted plug-in.
>   The target plug-in is not moved, removed, or modified in any way.
>
> Since the fragment's resources are located by the classloader, the plug-in developer has no need to know whether resources are loaded from the plug-in's JAR file or one of its fragments' JAR files.

---

I suspect the classLoader detect `plugin.name` in the `de.support.help` plugin first before the `de.support.help.fragment` fragment.

At this point, I am not sure it can be done, since it has been attempted before (for the [Eclipse CheckStyle plugin](http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?thread_id=2206671&forum_id=274377)), without much success.

Comment: That sounds like it is not possible with resource files. But with Java classes it is working. Maybe i can patch the eclipse bundle loader to look first in a fragment and than in the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace the content of a file with a fragment - only add additional files. This is true both for classes, properties files, images, ...

There are several standard methods for solving this problem:

- you can add an extension point with this and other customer specific information.
- you can first look for a special file and this fall back to the general one - as done by Markus.
- you can have an optional dependency on a plugin with the relevant information.

I prefer the last solution as this also allows be to choose between alternative algorithms and other things that does not belong in .properties files...