# write eclipse junit plugin test

Tags: eclipse, plugins, junit, testing

where do i start on writing plugin test? I have written some toy plugins and would like to start on doing TDD with my plugins.

Comment: What kind of functionality would you like to test?  
As a matter of fact, JUnit plugin tests are just plain JUnit tests, there is nothing Eclipse-specific about them. The only difference is, that if you run you JUnit test as a JUnit plugin test, they will run inside an instance of Eclipse.

Comment: from the plugin test, how do you interact with eclipse? for example programmatically post a event to do some actions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your plugin are RCP (Rich Client Platform) plugins, with SWT, you could use **[SWTBot](http://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/)**.
Those test can be encapsulated into JUnit one:

[image: Run-as-config-create]

---

If your plugins are OSGi-based, you must be aware that OSGi bundle runs it's own class loader and therefore the classes appear not to be in the same package.
See "[Is OSGi the enemy of JUnit tests?](http://michaelscharf.blogspot.com/2008/04/is-osgi-enemy-of-junit-tests_17.html)"

> Make your test plugin a **[fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657756/patch-merge-plugin-properties-file-in-plugin-by-using-fragment/657903#657903)**.
> One problem is that other plugins cannot access classes defined in fragments (as Patrick Paulin points out in [a more detailed discussion about fragments in unit tests](http://rcpquickstart.wordpress.com/2007/06/20/unit-testing-plug-ins-with-fragments/)).
> Another problem is that `plugin.xml` in a fragment is ignored. And therefore you test plugin cannot contribute

From Patrick's article:

> A fragments looks much like a plug-in from the outside. It is represented as a separate project in your workspace, it contains a manifest that describes its contents, it is built and deployed as a jar. What makes a fragment different is that it contributes it’s resources at runtime to a single host plug-in. The classes in the fragment are therefore loaded by the host plug-in’s classloader.

[image: plugin unit test]

> By placing our unit tests in fragments, we can provide our tests access to the non-public methods of the classes under test. Also, because the source code and test code are actually part of the same plug-in, there are no issues related to non-exported packages. Test classes will have access to all packages in the plug-in, whether they are exported or not.
>
> The main disadvantage to this fragment based approach is that it is difficult to aggregate unit tests into a master test suite. While it’s easy to create a test suite that includes the tests within a fragment, it’s not so easy to create a suite that includes the tests in multiple fragments.

---

If your plugins need just some simple testing, a [JUnit test](http://www.laliluna.de/eclipse-junit-testing-tutorial.html) suite is enough

> Create a new test case BookTest in the package test.yourpackage, Right click on the package and choose "`New > JUnit Test Case`".

[image: new test case]